# How to modify Choice field values (add & remove) without altering the original entries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working with a SharePoint list that has a "Category" column, which is a choice field, let's just say the categories are A,B,C,D (right now) for simplicity.  At the beginning of the fiscal year (1.5 months) these will not be the same- some additions and deletions will be needed, but we need to make sure the original list values for this field do not change (the ones that have already been entered).

If I modify the Choice field values directly to remove an item, let's say A, will it remove all instances of A throughout the list?  ie. Am I safe to edit this field directly, or should I create a "Historical Category" column to store the old values.

Answer (score 1):

Just set up a test list with a choice column containing values 1,2,3,4.  Created a few list entries, then modified the choice column values to 11,12,13,14.  Original list entry values for the choice column did not change (ie they were preserved).  My conclusion is that it seems like modifying the choice column values will not alter the original list entries, although you must be careful to not overwrite them with one of the newly modified values.